# Test Class for Generated Pdf and Attachment

Tags: unit-test

I need to write test class for it When order  status is updated to 'Activated' and at least one orderLineItems Product boolean field is true then generate Pdf and attach to that order.I have already written the Controller and V.F page. Below is a part of code.It is working Properly. But when i write test class its throwing error

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback before calling out

Below is my test class Please suggest me what can i do.
I am new to salesforce Please help.

I have a this class:

```
public with sharing class Standard_OrderHelper {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void generateShippingPdfCall(Id OrderId, String userSessionId)
    {

        String addr = 'https://' + Label.Org_Instance +'.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/attachShippingPDF';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint( addr );
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + userSessionId);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');

        Map<String, String> postBody = new Map<String,String>();
        postBody.put('OrderId', OrderId);
        String reqBody = JSON.serialize(postBody);

        req.setBody(reqBody);
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(req);  
    }
}
```

and this class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/attachShippingPDF/*')
Global without sharing class AttachShippingPDFContent{
    @HttpPost
    global static void attachPDF(ID OrderId) { 

      Order ord = [Select Ship_Name__r.Name, OrderNumber from Order where Id =: OrderId];

        PageReference PDfref = Page.GenerateOrderShippingPdf;
        PDfref.getParameters().put('id', orderId); 

        Blob b = PDfref.getContentAsPDF();

        Attachment attach  = new Attachment();
        attach.ContentType = 'application/pdf';
        attach.Body = b ;
        attach.ParentId = orderId;
        attach.Name = 'test Inc Shipping  ' +ord.Ship_Name__r.Name;
        insert attach;

        system.debug('Attach' + attach);

        //ord.OrderNumber =  orderNumber;
       // update ord;
        //update Is;

    }
}
```

and this test:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData = true)
public with sharing class Test_ShippingPdf {

    private Static List<Account> accList {
        get{
            if(accList == null){
                accList = new List<Account>{
                   new Account(Name = 'testacc', BillingCountry = 'India',RecordTypeId = AccountHelper.Account_ChannelPartner_RTID,Type = 'Distributor' , Reseller_Type__c = 'Parallels'),
                   new Account(Name = 'testacc1', BillingCountry = 'India',RecordTypeId = AccountHelper.Account_ChannelPartner_RTID ,Type = 'Distributor', Reseller_Type__c = 'Parallels'),
                   new Account(Name = 'testacc2', BillingCountry = 'India',RecordTypeId = AccountHelper.Account_ChannelPartner_RTID ,Type = 'Distributor', Reseller_Type__c = 'Parallels')

                };
                insert accList;
            }
            return accList;
        }
    }  

    public static testMethod void Test_Shipping(){

        Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'Test con', Email = 'test@test756.com', AccountID = accList[0].Id);
        insert con;

        Product2 prodObj= new Product2(Name = 'Test' ,isActive = true, zBox__c=true);
        insert prodObj;

        Product2 prodObj2= new Product2(Name = 'Test prod3' ,isActive = true, zBox__c=true);
        insert prodObj2;

        Product2 prodObj3= new Product2(Name = 'Test prod 2' ,isActive = true, zBox__c=true);
        insert prodObj3;

        PriceBookEntry pbeObj = new PriceBookEntry();
        pbeObj.Product2Id = prodObj.Id;
        pricebook2 standardpb = [select id from pricebook2 where isstandard = true];
        pbeObj.CurrencyIsoCode = UserInfo.getDefaultCurrency();
        pbeObj.UnitPrice = 200;
        pbeObj.PriceBook2Id = standardpb.Id;
        pbeObj.isActive = true;
        insert pbeObj;

        PriceBookEntry pbeObj2 = new PriceBookEntry();
        pbeObj2.Product2Id = prodObj2.Id;
        pbeObj2.CurrencyIsoCode = UserInfo.getDefaultCurrency();
        pbeObj2.UnitPrice = 100;
        pbeObj2.PriceBook2Id = standardpb.Id;
        pbeObj2.isActive = true;
        insert pbeObj2;

        PriceBookEntry pbeObj3 = new PriceBookEntry();
        pbeObj3.Product2Id = prodObj3.Id;
        pbeObj3.CurrencyIsoCode = UserInfo.getDefaultCurrency();
        pbeObj3.UnitPrice = 100;
        pbeObj3.PriceBook2Id = standardpb.Id;
        pbeObj3.isActive = true;
        insert pbeObj3;

        Accumatica__c act = new Accumatica__c(Account__c = accList[2].Id, Acumatica_ID__c = '1023652984', Entity_Number__c = '12');
        insert act;

        Test.startTest(); 

        Order ord = new Order(Type = 'BX', Distributor__c = accList[2].id, PoDate = System.today(), PoNumber = '12345', Acumatica_Entity_Id__c = '12', zDelivery_Method__c='testDelivery', 
                                            Ship_Name__c = accList[1].id, AccountId = acclist[1].Id, Status = 'Draft', EffectiveDate = System.today(), PriceBook2Id = standardpb.Id);
        insert ord;

        PageReference pageRef = Page.GenerateOrderShippingPdf;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 

        OrderItem oitm = new OrderItem(OrderId = ord.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbeObj.id, Unitprice  = 100 ,Quantity = 1, Order_Line_Number__c = 1);
        insert oitm;

        OrderItem oitm2 = new OrderItem(OrderId = ord.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbeObj2.id, Unitprice  = 150 ,Quantity = 2, Order_Line_Number__c = 2);
        insert oitm2;

        OrderItem oitm3 = new OrderItem(OrderId = ord.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbeObj3.id, Unitprice  = 50 ,Quantity = 3, Order_Line_Number__c = 3);
        insert oitm3;

        delete oitm2;

        generateshippingPdfController crtl = new generateshippingPdfController(new ApexPages.StandardController(oitm));

        ord.Status = 'Activated';
        update ord;
        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock(); 
        mock.setStaticResource('NameOfStaticResourceContainingResponseBodyString'); 
        mock.setStatusCode(200); // Or other appropriate HTTP status code 
        mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml'); // Or other appropriate MIME type like application/json 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Test.stopTest();
    } 

}`
```

Comment: Have you looked at your debug log? What does it tell you?

Comment: @Keith C. Yes iit is saying 'You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out'.